# How best to remove all UIViewcontrollers and goto a single UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application with the option to change a users password.  The reset password process is all done via web links.  When the process is complete, the user returns to their app.  Given that the password has now been changed, i would like to log the user out.

This is done when a user makes a request to the server for information and my server code will respond with a custom code to let the app know that the password has been changed.  In this instance the code is '177'.
I have attempted to present the user with the 'login' uiviewcontroller - but without success.  the screen just freezes.  Please can someone advise?

```
if code == 177{
                // INVALID API KET USED. LOG USER OUT
                print("INVALID API KET USED. LOG USER OUT")

                GlobalFunction.logout(action: {
                    // GO TO LOGIN VIEWCONTROLLER
                    print("GO TO LOGIN PAGE")
                    let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! MyLoginViewController
                    self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })

                return
            }
```

SECOND CLASS:

```
class GlobalFunction{

// LOG USER OUT OF APPLICATION
static func logout(action: @escaping (() -> ())){
    // Remove logged in user credentials
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "userId")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "firstname")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "firstname")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "api_key")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    print("user logged out")
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have to run the UI events on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! MyLoginViewController
    self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```